# Azure container instance create in existing vnet from CLI

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I'm following the documentation to create a container instance in an existing vnet and pass the vnet's ID as the --vnet parameter as follows:

```
az container create \
    --resource-group 123
    <...>
    --vnet 944xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxb0c9b0
```

But instead, Azure creates a new vnet with the name of if ID that I've passed.

Is it a bug?

Documentation link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create

```
--vnet
The name of the VNET when creating a new one or referencing an existing one. Can also reference an existing vnet by ID. This allows using vnets from other resource groups.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran below CLI command including VNet ID, it created **container instance** inside new VNet with passed ID like below:

```bash
az container create \
  --name sricontainer \
  --resource-group myresourcegroup \
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld \
  --vnet 5426cefe-5382-44c8-80b9-xxxxxxxx \
  --subnet default
```

**Response:**

[image]

To create Azure container instance in **existing** VNet, you need to pass **`ResourceID`** of VNet that can be found here:

[image]

When I ran the below CLI command by passing **ResourceID** in `--vnet` parameter, it created container instance in **existing** VNet successfully like this:

```bash
az container create \
  --name devicontainer \
  --resource-group myresourcegroup \
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld \
  --vnet /subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/srivnet \
  --subnet default
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to pass **Resource ID** of existing VNet in `--vnet` parameter.

**Reference:**

[Deploy container group to Azure virtual network - Azure Container Instances | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#deploy-to-existing-virtual-network)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The documentation I was referring to isn't too wordy.